# How to solve this equation $ (c^2+v^2)(\dot u )^2 = (\dot v)^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$ (c^2+v^2)(\dot u )^2  = (\dot v)^2$

$\dot u$ means diffrential of u, and c is a constant,

does the answer is $u = \log(v+ \sqrt{v^2+c^2}) + constant$ ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(c^2+v^2)\left(\frac{du}{dt} \right)^2=\left(\frac{dv}{dt} \right)^2$$
$$\frac{du}{dv}=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+v^2}}$$
$$u=\pm\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{c^2+v^2}}$$
$$u=\pm \ln\left| v\pm\sqrt{c^2+v^2}\right|+C$$
In order to not loosing a part of the solutions, do not forget the $\pm$ and the absolute value.

Comment: Thanks to Did for the correction. The two constants $c$ and $C$ are generally not the same.